# Sack team_id leaking in source code

Tags: penetration-test, bug-bounty

I found slack team_id in vdp source code, is it a sensitive token if yes how can I use it for a PoC?

Answer (score 1):

Team_id is not a sensitive token in slack, nor can it be used in a Proof-of-Concept. The team_id variable is just used to indicate the ID of the team's slack channel in a programmatic way. If you're looking for bugs in slack, imo I think their websockets implementation may be worth a look if you're looking for potential targets.